# как вывести числа set c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set <int> s;        
    int n, k, m, size;
    cin >> size >> n;
    int arr[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        s.insert(arr[i]);
 }

    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
        cout << s.begin();
        s.pop();
    }

}
```

где у меня ошибка?

Comment: класс не имеет метод  pop(), а чтобы выводить, не нужно удалять

Comment: `for(const auto& e:s)std::cout << e << std::endl;`

Comment: А компилятор вам разве не сказал, где у вас ошибка???

Answer (score 0):

А в чём тут проблема ?

1 ый способ:

```
for (std::set<int>::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << *it << ' ';
}
```

2 ой способ (как уже отметили в комментариях):

```
for (const auto& el: s)
{
    std::cout << el << ' ';
}
```

А ошибка у вас в другом месте, а именно:

```
int n, k, m, size;
cin >> size >> n;
int arr[size]; // Здесь
```

Размер массива созданного на стеке должен иметь константный тип и быть известен во время компиляции, тоесть либо замените `int arr[]` на `std::vector<int> arr(size);`
либо сделайте `size` `const` таким образом:

```
const int size = ...;
int arr[size];
...
```